# Pegar Dado Específico de Array multidimensional

Tags: php, array

Olá,

Estou tentando pegar um dado específico de um array mas não estou conseguindo. Consigo listar até uma dimensão mas a seguinte não... alguém dá um help por favor.

```
$dados = 'https://api.hgbrasil.com/finance/stock_price?key=53615266&symbol=petr3';
$dadoscont = file_get_contents($dados);
$obj = json_decode($dadoscont,true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($obj);
```

Assim eu pego os dados no seguinte formato:

```
Array
(
[by] => symbol
[valid_key] => 1
[results] => Array
    (
        [PETR3] => Array
            (
                [symbol] => PETR3
                [name] => Petróleo Brasileiro S.A. - Petrobras
                [region] => Brazil/Sao Paolo
                [currency] => BRL
                [market_time] => Array
                    (
                        [open] => 10:00
                        [close] => 17:30
                        [timezone] => -3
                    )

                [market_cap] => 95695.1
                [price] => 31.42
                [change_percent] => -1.29
                [updated_at] => 2020-01-15 14:11:45
            )

    )

[execution_time] => 0
[from_cache] => 1
)
```

Consigo pegar a primeira dimensão assim:

```
print_r($obj[results]);
```

Mas a que me interessa é a [price].
Já li o  tentei inclusive com foreach mas não deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderá acessar desta forma:

```
//Montagem do seu array:

$teste = Array("by" => "symbol", 
               "valid_key" => 1,
               "results" => Array (
                   "PETR3" => Array (
                       "symbol" => "PETR3",
                       "name" => "Petróleo Brasileiro S.A. - Petrobras",
                       "region" => "Brazil/Sao Paolo",
                       "currency" => "BRL",
                       "market_time" => Array (
                           "open" => "10:00",
                           "close" => "17:30",
                           "timezone" => "-3"
                        ),
                       "market_cap" => "95695.1",
                       "price" => 31.42,
                       "change_percent" => -1.29,
                       "updated_at" => "2020-01-15 14:11:45"
                    )

            ),
    "execution_time" => 0,
    "from_cache" => 1
);

//Acesso da posição price que você precisa.
$teste['results']['PETR3']['price']
```

A saída com o `var_dump()` será:

```
float(31.42)
```

A cada posição que você precisar acessar, basta como fazer neste exemplo.

Segue um exemplo funcional no [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0mv0-6bjr)